# Should one ever use the word "please" in an order or demand?

Tags: politeness

A police officer who pulls over a driver might ask to see his “license and registration, please.” Similarly, a border official might ask for a “passport, please.” However, in these situations, the asked party doesn’t have the option to refuse.

Does the word “please” imply that the addressee has the option not to obey the request?

Comment: Whether or not *please* implies that (which it does not), what options you do or do not have in such cases is regulated by laws, not by grammar rules.

Comment: I wasn't asking whether the addressee has such a right (obviously no criminal can say "Ha! The officer said please, so I don't have to do it!"). I was asking whether the asker used the word appropriately.

Comment: Similarly, if one discussed a police officer using a double negative like "You don't have no right to leave," one wouldn't be discussing whether the addressee is then granted that right.

Comment: When Mr Wolf said: "Pretty please with sugar on top - clean the f**king car", he didn't intend to imply there was any choice in the matter.

Comment: @BrianHooper: but that was intentionally ironic.

Comment: You always have the option to refuse, whether it is an order, a request, or whatever. Simply put, sometimes the negative consequences of refusing make it _seem_ like you don't have the option, but really you do. There are times when it is _bad_ or _unlawlful_ but really, you still have the option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Please* serves to distinguish a request from a command, but just because something is phrased as a request, that doesn't mean you can refuse it. A business owner who says "Ma'am, I'll have to ask you to leave" is being more polite than one who just says "Out!", but neither can be denied.

In your specific examples, I think that politeness is a major factor, but another factor might be that an utterance like "Passport" is very open-ended — passport *what*? — whereas "Passport, please" is more clearly a request. (It's still vague, in that it doesn't specify exactly what the passport-related request is, but I'm guessing that it's less liable to cause confusion.)

Comment: I don't really agree that 'Please' serves to distinguish a request from a command, I'm afraid. In both cases it tends to support it. In the case of your business owner, he is more likely to get a positive result using politeness for his command than by simply saying "Out!" Perhaps ultimately neither can be denied but the latter example is likely to meet more resistance, if only for the expectation of #Please."

Comment: @TonyBalmforth: In the case of the business owner, he *didn't* use "please"; instead, he used the construction "ask [person] to [verb]". Or do you also think that *that* construction can express a command?

Comment: @TonyBalmforth: (BTW, this might be clearer if we explicitly separate the semantics from the pragmatics. I think that "please" or "ask [person] to [verb]" *semantically* denotes a request, but a semantic request can still function *pragmatically* as a command.)

Comment: 'Please serves to distinguish a request from a command'. 'Please' may be added to imperative sentences (eg 'Please lower your voice') as well as of course interrogative and even exclamatory sentences. 'Commands' are more prescriptive than 'requests' and backed by authority, but this does not mean that the politeness marker may not be used. 'Please Do Not Smoke Sign ... Remind all employees and visitors that it is against the law to smoke on your premises, except from in designated smoking areas. ... 
Signs comply with BS EN ISO 7010 UK & EU Legislation', for instance, is to be found at ...

Comment: [Bathsignsdigital.co.uk/please-do-not-smoke-sign](http://www.bathsignsdigital.co.uk/please-do-not-smoke-sign-3499-p.asp). 'You will please take off your hat' is another obvious command rather than request. // See choster's answer. // There has been a thread where endorsement for leaving question marks off polite requests (even when they have the forms of related questions) is provided.

Comment: The examples I gave did not illustrate the 'command as opposed to a less authoritative request' usage (apologies), and I'd agree that the use of 'please' with _many_ requests could improperly imply weakness in the commander.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I see. So, I think we agree about how "please" is used, but disagree about the meaning of "request". I have no problem with something like, "To comply with federal safety regulations, we request that you refrain from smoking." And conversely, I have no problem with something like "'Give it to me,' he commanded", even if the "command" is not backed by any power or authority. For me the difference between a "command" and a "request" is that the latter is more formal or more polite, rather than that the former is more authoritative.

Comment: But the relevant definition for 'command'  from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/command) is ' **command** N _1 An authoritative order_ and that of 'request' from [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/request_1) is **request** _an act of asking for something in a polite or formal way_. The former does not necessarily preclude politeness, and the latter certainly does not mandate any hint of authority.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Hmm​, thanks. So I guess we agree about "please"; I'm wrong about "command"; you're wrong about "request"; and "command" and "request" aren't really binary alternatives, in that they address different dimensions.

Answer (score 9):

Per [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/please?show=1&t=1343920366), "please" is:

> —used as a function word to express politeness or emphasis in a request

It expresses politeness, regardless of whether the request is meant to be optional or not.

Answer (score 8):

I am almost bristling at the question 'should one *ever (my italics)* use the word "please" in an order or demand?'  There again, that may be traditional British sensitivity! In my opinion it should *always* be used out of courtesy except for a limited number of circumstances, mainly military or para-military orders.

I would certainly expect bosses, public servants, shop assistants - in fact just about anyone issuing a demand to temper it with politeness. Occasionally some have tried to omit it with me and have found out to their cost!

Answer (score 5):

*Please* simply indicates politeness or friendliness here; it changes nothing about the validity or legality of the underlying request. It is intended to signal that the official is being more polite than absolutely necessary, and it is human nature to be more cooperative with someone who is polite than someone who is not.

If you go to a restaurant, you aren't *required* to say *please* and *thank you* to the waiter but you probably will, for the same reason.

From a certain point of view, you do have the option to refuse. The consequences for that refusal are probably unpleasant, however, which is why the official can afford to use a gentle rhetorical question instead of an imperative, and why you get better service from a waiter who wants to please you as opposed to one who is merely afraid of losing his job.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, and for at least one professional psychologist I know, the "please" **does** imply optionality.

However, she and I were speaking of addressing commands to children, and as your comment notes, the other factor in the situation, force backed authority, rules out the optionality. Although, as already pointed out by @choster, one could choose to be arrested or denied entry to a country by refusing to produce the relevant documents.

As to "whether the asker used the word appropriately" *appropriately* is hard to define.  As others have already pointed out there is both a politeness associated with please and a possible emphasis of the request.  Particularly in the case of emphasis the questioner used the term appropriately, and for many people the absence of politeness would be worse than any technical ambiguity of usage.  That said, commands have a specific form, as @TonyBalmforth pointed out regarding military orders.

As a native (American) English speaker I would never argue that the questioner's grammar was incorrect, but the use of please in any command causes me minor annoyance.

Comment: There is some ambiguity about the officer's powers.  For example, the officer may say "License and registration please" when in fact the officer is empowered to demand them.  The officer may also say "May I search your car please" when in fact absent the subject's consent, the officer would have needed a warrant.  This is to the officer's advantage.  If the subject refuses a mandatory request, the officer can simply repeat it in the form of an unambiguous command.  If the subject accepts an optional request thinking it mandatory, then the officer's powers have been effectively enlargened.

Answer (score 0):

*Please* (not the verb, of course) is classed, according to Bruce Fraser at http://webh01.ua.ac.be/gramis/publications/Vandenbergen_Handbook%20of%20Pragmatics_Pragmatic%20markers_270709.pdf , as being in one of the subclasses of **pragmatic markers**. This is generally a fine article, but I'd go with the arguments above that *please* does not automatically change an order into a mere request (rather than with the opposite view stated in this article).
I'd put 'please' (along with the non-adverbial and non-adjectival usage of 'kindly') in the 'politeness marker' subclass (though with a different tone, both can be used to convey irritation). *Please* and *kindly* are types of what Wikipedia terms 'hedges', devices used to convey politeness or sympathy, to take the potential sharpness out of a statement or command. Not all hedges are pragmatic markers; euphemisms contribute semantic content.

'Would you please just put the injured bird out of its misery' contains four hedging devices: a modal downtoner (which I believe Fraser would claim *was* a pragmatic marker but not in the concrete - word or phrase - sense; his term here would, I think, be a *lexical marker* - an indication within the basic sentence structure itself rather than an adjunct), two pragmatic markers, and a euphemism.

Pragmatic markers (words or phrases) are devices used to facilitate (lubricate?) interpersonal communication rather than modify the *content* of a statement. Some are traditionally known as *sentence adverbials*, *comment clauses*; a more recent term for some is *sentence connectors*.

Answer (score -1):

I think when someone uses the word "please" in a command, that person is only trying to be more polite with his/ her words. "Please" should be use both as a request and a command.

Answer (score -1):

Working in an editorial processing environment, I find the word please to be essential in keeping day-to-day operations moving smoothly. Our work is constructed of requests. Our engineering staff uniformly phrases requests by leading with the word "can." As in, "Can you move this paragraph to the end of the column?" Obviously, I can do that. Do you think that is something you are going to ask me to do?  It is amazing to me how substituting the word "can" with the word "please" changes the entire meaning, from an inquiry to a directive. The directive form carries a bit of responsibility with it, which is probably the main reason people avoid it. Also, when the deadline looms and people are growing nervous, the habitual use of the word please works to keeps things on a professional level.

Comment: (1) Only a pedant would say that "Can you move this paragraph to the end of the column?" is an inquiry.  It is a politely stated request.  (2) At the risk of splitting hairs: it's not a matter of ***substituting*** one word for another, it's a matter of ***removing*** the word "can" (or, to be more precise, the words "can you").  "Can you please move this paragraph to the end of the column?" is still a politely stated request; "Move this paragraph to the end of the column." is a directive (or command).

Comment: Sorry, but I have too much experience in an actual editorial environment to have much patience with  "requests" phrased as evasive protections of willful ignorance.  I would prefer to not call them "requests" at all and instead refer to them as "work orders."  But then they would have to be direct and to the point, without the wiggle room provided by a "can you." Oh yeah, and forget about a markup. Instead, lists of changes in emails or delivered over the phone (on their cell driving down the highway with the windows down), based on their recollection of the page in question. Amazing really.

Comment: "Can you please move this paragraph to the end of the column?" The words, "Can you" are unnecessary and contribute nothing to the meaning/function of the sentence. The question mark becomes unnecessary. Simple statements are preferred over questions in this context.